# Use PowerPoint variable in Excel (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint Presentation and an Excel file. In my PPT I use a public variable `Public cnt As Long` and the following two functions to add to `cnt` or subtract (as example):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
cnt = cnt + 1
Me.CommandButton3.Caption = "cnt up = " & cnt
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
cnt = cnt - 1
Me.CommandButton3.Caption = "cnt down = " & cnt
End Sub
```

Users will click on one of the two buttons during the PPT show which will add or subtract from the `cnt` variable. So during the PPT show `cnt` may change from 1 to 2 then to 3 and so on.

What I want is to document the value of `cnt` in an excel file. So for example during the PPT show value of `cnt` should be shown in cell "A1". Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible for Powerpoint to "talk to" Excel like that.

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: Add a reference to `Microsoft.Excel`Object library into your VBA project,  create an `Excel.Application` object within the Powerpoint Code and use it to open an Excel Workbook and write to the sheet of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a late binding example: (this goes into Powerpoint VBA)

```
Option Explicit

Public braX As Integer

Public Sub test()
  braX = 10
  Dim xlApp As Object
  Dim xlBooks As Object
  Dim xlBook As Object
  Dim xlSheet As Object
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  xlApp.Visible = True
  Set xlBooks = xlApp.workbooks
  Set xlBook = xlBooks.Add()
  Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
  xlSheet.Range("A1") = braX
End Sub
```